# Using Cellular network to download SoundCloud File returns wml file?

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, soundcloud, wml

I have this weird problem. I obtain download_url from SoundCloud HTTP API /tracks, then if downloadable, I use the download_url with NSURLConnection to download.

When using wifi to download, everything works fine!
However, when using cellular network, I could not download the audio data. Instead, the returned data from NSURLConnection delegate of the same download_url is:

```
<!DOCTYPE wml PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD WML 1.1//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/wml_1.1.xml"><wml><card id="video"><onevent type="ontimer"><go href="http://202.140.78.214:80/uts?v30=http%3A%2F%2Fec%2Dmedia%2Esoundcloud%2Ecom%2FG4GyC2wLcMla%3Ff10880d39085a94a0418a7ef61b03d5275edf83695e0cd6a5a31bf03ecb97a587db1d8ceca2809c3d90cae95111668a3a66dabd8e36a89f26145880956%26AWSAccessKeyId%3DAKIAJNIGGLK7XA7YZSNQ%26Expires%3D1401785465%26Signature%3DTwL%252F1dS4xW2oPFB5chUmDj%252Fu03Y%253D&amp;c=COsEMIeL8I"></go></onevent><timer value="10"/><anchor>Back<go href=""/></anchor></card></wml>
```

Further test showed that it only happened to one cellular network provider, not the other one that I tested. Any idea what could possibly gone wrong? Why is there such a wml?

Thanks